# Weird behavior of .hover() on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I am confused on why .hover() is behaving this way on iOS.

On desktop I have portfolio gallery images that link off to individual pages of my work. When you hover on any image, it slightly fades and a title animates in. Whenever I view the same gallery on my phone, the fade and animation happens on touch but doesn't take me to the work landing page until I tap it again. It seems like it's getting stuck on the hover in. Any thoughts?

I know I could check for browser width and disable the hover once I start getting into mobile breakpoints but I would rather this feature still be available on the desktop browser. I am totally fine with removing the hover behavior all together in mobile only if possible.

my code:

```
/*targeted element*/
<a class="workBox" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $the_query->ID ) ?>" ><div class="work" style="background: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>') center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div><div class="workTitle"><?php echo get_the_title( $the_query->post_title ); ?><div class="landingOffered"><em><?php echo $service; ?></em></div></div></a>

$('.workBox').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.work').css('opacity' , '0.1');
        $(this).find('.workTitle').fadeTo(200 ,1);
        $(this).find('.landingOffered').velocity({'margin-top': '-5px'}, 200);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.work').css('opacity' , '1');
        $(this).find('.workTitle').fadeTo(200 , 0);
        $(this).find('.landingOffered').velocity({'margin-top': '10px'}, 200); 
 });
```

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more code and markup in order for people to help you: The markup of the elements in question, and the touch or click handlers attached to them if any. I wouldn't expect the quoted handler to be triggered by your phone at all.

Comment: Hi T.J! I added one of the targeted elements for reference but that is basically it in terms of code. I wouldn't expect it to be targeted either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the client is a mobile phone with a fairly straight forward check like this :

```
function clientIsMobilePhone() 
{ 
    return  navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i);
}
```

And then do the following :

```
/*targeted element*/
<a class="workBox" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $the_query->ID ) ?>" ><div class="work" style="background: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>') center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div><div class="workTitle"><?php echo get_the_title( $the_query->post_title ); ?><div class="landingOffered"><em><?php echo $service; ?></em></div></div></a>

$('.workBox').hover(function() {

        if(clientIsMobilePhone()) return;

        $(this).find('.work').css('opacity' , '0.1');
        $(this).find('.workTitle').fadeTo(200 ,1);
        $(this).find('.landingOffered').velocity({'margin-top': '-5px'}, 200);
    }, function() {

        if(clientIsMobilePhone()) return;

        $(this).find('.work').css('opacity' , '1');
        $(this).find('.workTitle').fadeTo(200 , 0);
        $(this).find('.landingOffered').velocity({'margin-top': '10px'}, 200); 
 });
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. I know a lot of people cringe at device sniffing code but this seems universal enough that it shouldn't be an issue. Curious to know what the "/i" means?

Comment: it's for a case insensitive search. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: funnily enough, i usualy cringe at the readability of regular expressions, but this one ain't so bad.